# parseInt method in javascript returns wrong values

Tags: javascript

I have parsing values to integer in my function using parseInt, but when i parse the `-4.450217635509901e-7` to integer it returns `-4`.

```
parseInt(-4.450217635509901e-7)=> -4
```

`-4.450217635509901e-7` is nothing but `-0.000000450217635509901` so it should return 0 but for me its returning -4.

How to parse the values having exponential?

Comment: Are you looking for `Math.floor` or `Math.ceil` or `Math.round`? It doesn't seem like `parseInt` is what you need here, as you already have a number.

Comment: ParseInt discards decimal values

Comment: There is no exponent to parse, since the number literal will already be evaluated when `parseInt` is called. All it gets is a number value. `parseInt` is intended to be used with strings. Please explain what you are trying to achieve. What happens in your case is that the number is converted to a string, and it will be formatted using scientific notation (basically the same notation you used for the number literal). `parseInt` iterates over every character, collecting those it understands (leading +/- and digits). `.` is neither so it stops and converts the collected chars to a number.

Answer (score 2):

parseInt parses a string as an integer.  You are giving it a float (I don't even know why that is working).  If you want to round it, use your choice of rounding methods from the Math object.